# Fullscreen image view not behaving correctly after scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I've created a full-screen image viewer as follows...

At the top of my `<body>` tag I have the following:

```
<div id="backdrop" class="hide"></div>
```

I then have some `<img>` tags that are toggled via JavaScript.

```
<img id="1" onClick="toggleSelect(1)" src="thumb.jpg" class="small" />
<img id="2" onClick="toggleSelect(2)" src="thumb.jpg" class="small" />
<img id="3" onClick="toggleSelect(3)" src="thumb.jpg" class="small" />
```

CSS:

```
#backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1000000;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

img.small {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 999999;
}

img.big {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 90%;
    z-index: 1000001;
}
```

The images and the backdrop basically have their classes toggled:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
toggleSelect: function(index) {
    if (images[index].selected)
    {           
        $("#"+index).addClass('small');
        $("#"+index).removeClass('big');

        $("#backdrop").addClass('hide');
        $("#backdrop").removeClass('show');

        images[index].selected = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#"+index).addClass('big');           
        $("#"+index).removeClass('small');

        $("#backdrop").addClass('show');
        $("#backdrop").removeClass('hide');

        images[index].selected = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

This all works well and good as you can see here:

[image: Working]

However, if I scroll down and then toggle the image, you can see it's problematic:

[image: Not Working]

Given this situation, is there any easy or convenient way to get the image to go fullscreen (90% height as set in the CSS) regardless of my current scroll position?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you able to create a fiddle?
As a gut feel, i would look into vw and vh units which is a percentage of the window width/height

Comment: is the img.big with position:absolute inside a container with position:relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by setting overflow hidden to body, when image is fullscreen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
toggleSelect: function(index) {
    if (images[index].selected)
    {           
        $("#"+index).addClass('small');
        $("#"+index).removeClass('big');

        $("#backdrop").addClass('hide');
        $("#backdrop").removeClass('show');

        $('html, body').css({overflow: 'auto'});

        images[index].selected = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#"+index).addClass('big');           
        $("#"+index).removeClass('small');

        $("#backdrop").addClass('show');
        $("#backdrop").removeClass('hide');

        $('html, body').css({overflow: 'hidden'});

        images[index].selected = true;
    }
}
</script>
```